# How to create the Case with Attachments in single Rest API call

Tags: rest-api, case, translation

I need to create a Case with Attachment(s) in Salesforce using Rest API. The Case Team should be assigned on created Case. Also the Case Feed Item should be created with some text where the uploaded attachments should be linked.

I know how to do it using one Rest API call for each operation. So in my case it will be 6 API calls for 3 attachments. At least I would like to reduce the API calls. Also some kind of transaction required in my case.

It is possible to do such operation in one API call at least for Case with Attachments? Can I use something like transaction with REST API?
Currently I'm looking into this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_composite_resources.htm).